# Flex-box display children divs side by side

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `.content-container` `div` that is set to `display: flex`, and children divs (`.message-body, .message-action`) that I want to show side by side, with the `.message-action` div floating to the right.

Here is what I am working off of:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZRZKdZ

As you can see, the `.message-action` div seems to be below the `.message-body` div.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `flex-direction:row` and not `column` on the container if you want them side-by-side (*read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction for more on this property*).

(*also remove the `float:right`*)

Updated pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qKwjNa